# How to create an ASP.NET application with a default web.config?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an ASP.NET 2.0 application (using C#), and for some reason when I create the initial application it doesn't create the web.config file. Is this normal? I haven't touched ASP.NET in some years so I am a little rusty. I tried creating the web.config manually but can't seem to get it just right. How can I create an ASP.NET application with a bundled web.config file? Thanks.

Comment: What development environment are you using?  That makes a difference for what's automatically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use VS2008 and when I hit F5, VS asks me if I want to create a default web.config (if one is not already present). What tools are you using for development ?

Answer (score 2):

From the Website menu, go to Add New Item, and pick "Web Configuration File." That will give you a vanilla web.config that you can start with.

Visual Studio will not create a web.config file for you if you create an Empty Web site, so that would be normal behavior. Otherwise, it will create one for you.

Comment: Visual Studio 2005. My apologies for not specifying. I just needed to compile with F5 and then I was prompted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way is just to hit F5.